# How to convert this gst-launch command from GStreamer 0.10 to 1.0?

Tags: gstreamer

This is to be converted:

```
gst-launch -v ximagesrc startx=0 starty=0 endx=800 endy=600 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1" ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

I found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0#ffmpegcolorspace) that

> The "ffmpegcolorspace" element has been replaced with the new
>   "videoconvert" element.

Simply replacing `gst-launch` with `gst-launch-1.0` and `ffmpegcolorspace` with `videoconvert` is not sufficient and produces an error:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link videoconvert0 to v4l2sink0

A simple `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink` works fine, while `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0` produces a different error:

> ERROR: from element
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0: Internal data
>   flow error.

Answer (score 3):

Two things, first, GStreamer changed the way they do caps, so `video/x-raw-yuv` becomes `video/x-raw,format=YUV9` (or one of many other formats).  So your caps would be wrong under GStreamer 1.0.

Secondly, you can probably trim your pipeline up a bit.  I'd guess you could do this:

`gst-launch -v ximagesrc startx=0 starty=0 endx=800 endy=600 ! videoconvert !  v4l2sink device=/dev/video0`

And if the frame rates don't match between the source and sink you'd have to add videorate:

`gst-launch -v ximagesrc startx=0 starty=0 endx=800 endy=600 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0`

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications. I attempted both lines but still get a data flow error. I also found [this](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/83), which looks like v4l2loopback could be the reason. If someone could confirm, I'd be happy to mark this as the answer.